# Is it possible to put JS scripts in PHP File?

Tags: php, html, refresh

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('ditwhales');

$studno=$_POST['studno'];

$command=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE studno= 

'$studno'");
$numrs=mysql_num_rows($command);

if ($numrs==0){
print 'Sorry but you are not one of the Whales. Please contact the web 

master and ask for registration of your Student No. Thank you!';
}

else{
$all=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM msgs");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($all)){

echo $row['message'] . "<br />";

};
}




?>
```

I have this code. But the thing is I want the else to refresh every 1 second. Is that even possible? I think the return function would work but I don't know how to use it. Can anyone help please?

Comment: every 1 second? do really need to refresh every 1 second, imagine 10000 users x 1second = 10000 requests x 60sec = 60000 requests per minute, that's spamming for me, better to increase the refresh  every 30secs or use websockets to push updates to clients.

Answer (score 1):

you can load the php file with javascript ajax every 1sec, also you can use a unlimited loop and put the sleep(1); there for refresh every 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

as Mohammad suggest, you can use client side scripting for this issue to call php file locate on the server and return answer, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callphp(){
    setTimeout('callphp()', 1000);
    xmlhttp = null;
    count = 0;
    var d = new Date();
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        // IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
RndString = d.getFullYear() + "" + d.getMonth() + "" + d.getDate() + ""  + d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes() + "" + d.getSeconds() + "" + count++;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'file.php?C=' + RndString,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    if(xmlhttp.responseText != ""){
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
}
</script>
```

please check it out and let us to know what happen.

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of confusing roles: php runs serverside, it returns the data you display to the client, usually full-blown HTML that the browser shows directly but it can also return just data in various formats such as [json](http://www.json.org/) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) when you use it as a provider for [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), which is a fancy way of calling a function by means of the php file endpoint and having it return the data.

If you want to manipulate how the client-side (usually a webbrowser) interacts with the user then you'll need to write code that interacts in that specific context, The unified way of doing that for browsers is by using [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

With javascript you can make your page (inter)active in many ways such as calling a routine every X seconds, by using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval).

```
var cMR;

function callMyResults(){
}

window.onload = function(){
    cMR = setInterval('callMyResults',5000);
}
;
```

to have your code called automatically when the page is loaded, we attach a function to the [onLoad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) event handler, this will execute everything in the function assigned to it, in our case it will set an interval of 5000 milliseconds upon which it will execute the CallMyResults() function everytime. The result of setInterval is saved in the cMR global so that it can later be used to stop the code executing on the interval if needed.

So currently this code does nothing. Javascript can call other pages and thus retrieve data by something that's now uniformly referred to as [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) Originally this was meant to retrieve XML documents which you then acted upon (or just simply [wrote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) into the currently displayed document). Later this has evolved to using json because this returns a javascript native element, making it easier to use and generally smaller in size to transfer over the network connection which makes the pages snappier.

Many libraries exist to do this easily, one of the most popular being [jquery](http://jquery.com/), but you could also just write your own calls using the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object (the basis of AJAX). You'll find plenty of examples of this on the web, like this one for [retrieving json data](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost4.shtml).

Generally speaking it is recommended you use an established library, for ease of use, your own sanity and just much nicer and easier accessible coding.

Finally on the PHP side you just gather your data as usual but you print it a bit differently, either as XML in your own specified format or by returning it as json by using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Which can be as simple as the following:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1',$user,$password);
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM msgs');
print json_encode($result->fetchAll());
```

Notice that I've used [PHP Data Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (commonly referred to as PDO) to access the database, this provides a uniform way of accessing databases, in case you ever switch to another [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) than the one you're using currently (mysql). The thing you'd need to adapt in that case would be the DSN string you supply to your [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) object when you instantiate it. The other very big advantage of PDO is that it protects you against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by providing methods to easily create a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to which you provide [parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) that are automatically quoted (and thus protected); the mysql_* family of functions are no longer recommended for use: eithr use PDO or use mysqli.

So, to give you a working example:

we have 1 client page: display.html and 2 server side pages for generating and returning the data (fillList.php and retrieveList.php )

**fillList.php**

```
<?php
    // we work with the following table
// create table list_data (`when` DATETIME NOT NULL);

    // make sure to adapt these settings to yours, including username and password
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=scratch;host=localhost','username','password');
$pdo->exec('INSERT INTO list_data VALUES (NOW())');
```

this will insert a new value inside the `when` column of the `list_data` table

**retrieveList.php**

```
<?php
    // make sure to adapt these settings to yours, including username and password
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=scratch;host=localhost','scratch','scratch');
    print json_encode($pdo->query('SELECT `when` FROM list_data 
                                   ORDER BY `when` DESC'
                                  )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
                      );
```

retrieves all values found in the `list_data` table ordered in descending order and returns the resulting associative array as a json object.

I decided to show you an example client page using jquery, make sure you download the latest [jquery-1.7.2.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) and place it in the same directory as this file.

**display.html**

```
<html><head><title>Refreshing List</title>
<script src="http://localhost/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
</head>
<body>

<p>this list refreshes every 5 seconds, a new value is inserted every 2 seconds</p>
<ul id="toRefresh">
<li>base</li>
</ul>
<script>

function fillList(){
  // we insert a new value in the database by calling fillList.php
  $.get("http://localhost/fillList.php");
}

function refreshList(){
  /* 
    we retrieve the json encoded data returned by retrieveList.php 
    and process it in our anonymous function
  */
  $.getJSON("http://localhost/retrieveList.php",function (data){
    var items = [];
// loop through the returned array
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
      // we passed an associative array so we can use the columnname: 'when'
      items.push("<li>when: " + val['when'] + "</li>");
});
    // clear the list and append the data to it
$("#toRefresh").empty();
$("#toRefresh").append(items.join(''));
  });
}

// jquery uses .ready() instead of window.onload = function(){}
$(document).ready(function (){
  // retrieve the data every 5 seconds
  setInterval(function(){refreshList();},5000);
  // insert additional new data every 2 seconds
  setInterval(function(){fillList();},2000);

  // we fill the list with its initial values
  refreshList();

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see jquery gives you an easy way to perform these operations. Run the display.html page and you'll see an always growing and refreshing list of mysql datetime values.